# Aliasing prefixes (not namespaces) in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, xml-namespaces

I want to change the prefix in the output from the prefix in the stylesheet itself.

XSLT file:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:a="nsA">
 <template match="/">
  <a:out/>
 </template>
</stylesheet>
```

What I get:

```
<a:out xmlns:a="nsA" />
```

What I want:

```
<b:out xmlns:b="nsA" />
```

Note that I want to change only the **prefix**, not the **namespace**. The element namespace-alias will translate only the namespace, leaving the prefix intact.

Bonus points if it is possible to remove the prefix completely:

```
<out xmlns="nsA" />
```

Note that the XSLT elements are not prefixed and the output elements are prefixed. It has to remain like that. I know that the problem could be solved with prefixing XSLT and un-prefixing output elements, but it's not an option. The to-be-output elements must have the prefix as provided in the stylesheet, only in the output should they be changed.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but why don't you just change the `xmlns:a="nsA"` in your stylesheet to `xmlns:b="nsA"`? Also, _I know that the problem could be solved with prefixing XSLT and un-prefixing output elements, but it's not an option._ Why is this not an option? You seem to be working with some limitations on how you are allowed to write your XSLT, but you haven't told us what they are.

Comment: It should also be noted that prefixes can be entirely arbitrary and it should not make one iota of difference if the prefix is "a:" or "b:" or "gobbledygook:" (or even a mixture of all of the three) as long as the namespace bound to the prefix/es is correct. If it does make a difference, then perhaps you should be addressing that problem  instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 leaves the choice of prefixes implementation-defined; XSLT 2.0 mandates that for literal result elements, the prefix in the output will be the same as that in the stylesheet. So you're hosed.

There are of course many ways to solve your problem if the constraints are relaxed. An entertaining solution would be to transform the stylesheet before executing it; a more pedestrian approach would be to transform the output as a post-processing step.

Answer (score 5):

> What I get:
>
> `<a:out xmlns:a="nsA" />`

No, that's not what you get - at least not what you should be getting. With a decent XSLT processor you will get an error telling you that the document is not a valid stylesheet.

> Note that the XSLT elements are not prefixed

Not sure why you would want that (it's akin to shooting yourself in the leg) but if you insist, you can define a default namespace for the stylesheet, and use the XSLT elements unprefixed, e.g.:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<template match="/">
    <!-- ... -->
</template>

</stylesheet>
```

However, in such case non-XSLT elements must be either prefixed or assigned a namespace explicitly.

> Bonus points if it is possible to remove the prefix completely:
>
> `<out xmlns="nsA" />`

If that's what you want, why don't you write exactly that?

Either one of these:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="nsA"
exclude-result-prefixes="a">

<template match="/">
    <element name="out" namespace="nsA"/>
</template>

</stylesheet>
```

or simply:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:a="nsA"
exclude-result-prefixes="a">

<template match="/">
    <out xmlns="nsA"/>
</template>

</stylesheet>
```

will produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<out xmlns="nsA"/>
```

Note that the `xmlns:a="nsA"` declaration is required only for the purpose of addressing elements in the source XML document that happen to be in the same "nsA" namespace. Otherwise it is entirely redundant.

Comment: Of course there is a default namespace for XSL elements. The problem is I don't have the full control over the stylesheet. XSL elements are unprefixed, output elements in the stylesheet are prefixed and I need output elements in the result file unprefixed or at least with the prefix under my control

Comment: @haael Okay, so what's problem then? I gave you a way to achieve exactly what you asked for, did I not?

Comment: +1 - @haael michael's point is that output elements _don't_ have to be prefixed in the stylesheet if you put an explicit `xmlns="nsA"` on each one.  Yes, you need to put the `xmlns` on every literal result element, and then a countermanding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` on any XSLT instructions that are nested inside it, but if you are consistent with the namespaces then the eventual output should only get one `xmlns="nsA"`, which the serializer will put at the root level.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="nsA"
    xmlns:b="nsA">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="b:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem I try to solve. This script will change the prefix from the source document to the result document. But I need to change prefix from the stylesheet to the result document.

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently working within constraints on how you are allowed to write your XSLT but have decided to keep them a secret from us (thank you for that), so we can only guess at what will meet your requirements.

If:

- Your XSLT engine supports some variety of the `node-set()` function
- You are allowed to modify the template that matches to the document root (or add one if there isn't one already)
- You are allowed to add new templates

Then the following should work for the "bonus" version of your request.

Add the following template (if you already have a template that matches the document root, replace the `<apply-templates />` in this one with the contents of your original template, and delete the original):

```
<template match="/">
  <variable name="result">
    <apply-templates />
  </variable>
  <!-- If you're using something other than exslt to get the node-set
       function, then use the namespace for that instead. -->
  <apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($result)" 
                   mode="fixupNamespace" 
                   xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" />
</template>
```

Add these three templates:

```
<template match="node() | @*" mode="fixupNamespace">
  <copy>
    <apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="fixupNamespace" />
  </copy>
</template>

<template match="*" mode="fixupNamespace">
  <element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="fixupNamespace" />
  </element>
</template>

<template match="a:*" mode="fixupNamespace">
  <element name="{local-name()}" namespace="nsA">
    <apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="fixupNamespace" />
  </element>
</template>
```

And you should be all set.